# Read AppSettings Data Console App .net Core 2.0

Tags: c#, json, parsing, console-application, config

Having trouble reading data from appsettings.json in a .netcore 2.0 console app looked at a bunch of examples syntax is not working/ any suggestions? the value in my appsettings.json looks like this
"OBNAME": {
    "OBKEY": "OBKPASS"

}

I basically want to assign the OBNAME values to a var in another class

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Binding a configuration to an object graph in .NET Core 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47863078/binding-a-configuration-to-an-object-graph-in-net-core-2-0)

Answer (score 0):

```
public const string ConfigurationFileName = "appsettings.json";


public static YourClass CreateConfiguration()
{

     var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()            
     .AddJsonFile(ConfigurationFileName);

     IConfigurationRoot configurationRoot = builder.Build();
     YourClass yourClass = new YourClass();
     configurationRoot.Bind(yourClass );
     return filePolicyConfiguration;

}
```

In `YourClass` put the properties like the appSettings.json built, put `OBNAME` 
 as property int this class.

Comment: I'm using this however getting errors such as this does not exist when I changes yourClass to the name of the obj in appsettings

Comment: maybe show your code it will make more understandable

Comment: You have clearly misused your variable names here. Went from yourClass to filePolicyConfiguration.

Comment: changed the variable name