# Binding options when appsettings has child objects

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I have `appsettings` that look like this:

```
{
   "ClassA": {
      "ClassB": {
        "ConnectionString": "Testing"
      }
}
```

```
public class ClassA
{
    public ClassB ClassB { get; set; }
}


public class ClassB
{
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
}
```

In the `Program.cs` I'm adding the options like so:

```
builder.Services.AddOptions<ClassA>()
        .Bind(configuration.GetSection("ClassA"));
```

When I inject `IOptions<ClassA>` into a class the `ClassB` child property is null. How do I bind the options with child properties?

Comment: services.Configure<ClassA>(configuration.GetSection("ClassA")));

Comment: You can check more info about it in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47864369/9114389)

Comment: @ViniciusAndrade When injection IOptions<ClassA> ClassB is null.

Comment: @ViniciusAndrade The answer you added a link to doesn't reflect what I'm trying to achieve. Keep in mind, I have a child objects here

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple implementation of a worker service with your same scenario

## Program.cs

```cs
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureServices((context,services )=>
                {
                    services.Configure<ClassA>(context.Configuration.GetSection("ClassA"));
                    services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
                })
                .Build();

            host.Run();
        }
    }
```

## Worker.cs

```cs
public class Worker : BackgroundService
    {
        private readonly IOptions<ClassA> _options;
        private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;

        public Worker(IOptions<ClassA> options, ILogger<Worker> logger)
        {
            _options = options;
            _logger = logger;
        }


        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Connection string from class b is: {connectionString}", _options.Value.ClassB.ConnectionString);
        }
    }
```

## Entities.cs

It's a file with all classes just for demonstration purpose, please don't use class like this.

```cs
public class ClassA
{
    public ClassB ClassB { get; set; }
}
public class ClassB
{
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
}
```

## appsettings.json

```json
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },

  "ClassA": {
    "ClassB": {
      "ConnectionString": "Testing"
    }
  }
}
```

## Output

[image]

Comment: Is it not possible to achieve the same but with `AddOptions`? I still need to validate settings.